# What species of spider lays their eggs in the flesh of the person they bite?

Tags: united-states, spider

I recently was bitten several times by a spider or spiders during an outing in southern Virginia, USA.  The bites looked really nasty for a couple of days, but are now subsiding and have stopped itching, so I am not worried.

A friend told me that a spider laid her eggs in the arm of one of his friends, and that eventually tiny spiders emerged from the swelling, and a doctor had to cut the wound open, deliver the rest of the spiders, and clean it.

This person is **not** prone to exaggeration, **but I am asking if this is characteristic of one or several species, or not uncommon among all spiders.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that to be a [Myth: Spiders can lay their eggs under human skin in wounds created by their bites.](https://www.burkemuseum.org/collections-and-research/biology/arachnology-and-entomology/spider-myths/myth-baby-spiders-bite)

It always happens to "a friend" not to the person relating the story.

However, there are several bugs that do: [11 Bugs That Will Lay Their Eggs Inside You](https://www.ranker.com/list/insects-that-lay-their-eggs-inside-human-beings/laura-allan).

The maggot from the botfly in the first picture looks particularly hideous.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the warning on the second link!